# Can the Bellman Equation be used for Finite time problems?

Tags: bellman-equations, recursive-macroeconomics

Its known that the Bellman equation in recursive macroeconomics is used for the following problems:

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\beta^tU(c_t)$$
$$s.t. c_t+k_{t+1}=f(k_t)$$
$$k_0>0$$

Im wondering if we can apply the bellman equation to problems with finite horizon. The reason why I ask is because it would be considerably easier solving a bellman for a policy function than to solve for these values sequentially.

Comment: I might not understand this question, but the answer seems to be trivially yes, since that's how (i.e. from finited time horizons) is how the Bellman equation is actually derived.  See 1.5 in https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~nwilliam/Econ712/lect7.pdf

Comment: My recent answer to this question may be helpful: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32711/dynamic-programming-optimal-consumption-savings-finite-horizon-problem/32867?noredirect=1#comment49850_32867